# How to pass state/props when redirecting to another route in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a signup form and after a user signs up, it will redirect to the email confirmation page(/confirmation) where a user types a confirmation code that I sent via an email. When a user submits a confirmation code, I want to send the code and a user's email to server-side.

My signup form code(simplified):

```
    constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {
             email: '',
             password: '',
             errors: {},
          }
       }
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.userSignup(this.state).then(
            () => {
               this.context.router.push({
                  pathname: '/confirmation'
               })
            },

         )
   }
   render(){ ...
```

I do not want to add any params to my path.
How can I pass `this.state.email` to confirmation page?

Comment: use react-router https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
 this.context.router.push({
     pathname: '/confirmation',
     state: {email: this.state.email}  
 })
```

and access state by:

```
  this.props.location.state.email
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your answer, was having the same issue

Comment: @Full-Hybrid no problem!

Comment: It's worth noting that context isn't stable or recommended in React.

Comment: If the page is refreshed the state will be lost

Comment: Does anybody know how to pass functions as props. I'm getting a DataCloneError

Comment: This is similar to the solution if you were using `<Redirect />` rather than `[...].push`; as detailed by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52064362/6333825) which also includes a link to the `react-router` documentation.

Comment: @Dan How do you do that when you wanna save this state to local state? Example `this.setState({email: this.props.location.state.email});`. I get an empty array, when I log it, but the props location state is not empty.

Answer (score 12):

What i have done to pass data without context object is by using history prop,

```
this.props.history.push({
             pathname:"/shopdetail",
             state:{
                 key:"value"
              }
            });
```

And in the ShopDetail component you can access the object like,

```
this.props.location.state.key
```

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to lose state upon a page refresh you can use local storage:

```
handleSubmit() {
  localStorage.setItem('email',
  JSON.stringify(this.state.email));
               }
```

and then retrieve from local storage on any other page, perhaps in componentWillMount:

```
componentWillMount(){
  let email = '';
  if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('email')) {
     email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email'));
    }
   this.setState({email: email})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### 2021

You can also redirect by this component from react-router:

```
...
if (shouldRedirect) {
     return <Redirect to={"/some-path"} state={{ value: "hey"}}>
}
return <div>Welcome</div>
```

Then use it in the new component:

```
...
const location = useLocation()
const value = location.state.value
```

If you are using typescript, add types to the state as such:

```
interface State {
    value: string
}
const location = useLocation<State>()
```