# ReactJS - Pass props with Redirect component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How should you pass props with the `Redirect` component without having them exposed in the url?

Like this `<Redirect to="/order?id=123 />"`? I'm using `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should first pass the props in Route where you have define in your App.js

```
<Route path="/test/new" render={(props) => <NewTestComp {...props}/>}/>
```

then in your first Component

```
<Redirect
            to={{
            pathname: "/test/new",
            state: { property_id: property_id }
          }}
        />
```

and then in your Redirected NewTestComp you can use it where ever you want like this

```
componentDidMount(props){
console.log("property_id",this.props.location.state.property_id);}
```

Comment: Underrated answer- this is a full solution; simply adding the line in the above answers doesn't properly pass the props.

Comment: This is the CRUCIAL part. Simple and very helpful to say the least!

Comment: Flagged as new correct answer since this one has more information.

Comment: can you elaborate on 'then in your first Component'?  I'm having trouble fitting this all together.  which component is the 'first component'?

Comment: @sammms not the author, but I believe they just meant in the Redirect Component. You can add this to any Redirect Component that you wish to pass props with, provided the Route component has a render prop set as a function. [See here for more about Redirect to](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/to-object), and [here for more about Route render](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

Comment: When I ran this code, it resulted in a blank page when I was returning `Redirect`

Comment: What if the rendered component is a function and not a class?

Answer (score 118):

You can pass data with `Redirect` like this:

```
<Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/order',
            state: { id: '123' }
        }}
/>
```

and this is how you can access it:

```
this.props.location.state.id
```

The [API docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation) explain how to pass state and other variables in Redirect / History prop.

Source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object

Comment: Do I need the `BrowserHistory` component to get this working?

Comment: No you don't. As long as you're using any router in your routes.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll mark your response as the solution as soon at the timer expired! :)

Comment: This solution doesn't follow the html 5 browser history specification, data should be passed in a state object.

Comment: @anas this is what the library author recommends: 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation

Comment: @SakhiMansoor the url you provided says that you should `npm install history`? What if I don't have that done, or is it already in the `react-router-dom` package?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Yes the object should contain `pathname`, `search`, `state`, etc which are values used by the browser history. Any custom values should be included in the `state` object which is one level down. It's cleaner and separates what's used by the browser history from your own custom object.

Comment: Thank you @Anas and SakhiMansoor for the help. You guys both deserve the solution mark ! :)

Comment: Yes I agreed @Anas but I'm more interested any particular reason behind this ?

Comment: One reason would be, let's say in the next release they add `id` to their api, now you have a conflict.

Comment: That’s one of the concern. But we should read migration docs before updating packages and yes I would edit my answer. Btw thanks it’s a learning for me as well.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I tried the same code but it gives me this error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'LocationDescriptor<any>'.

Comment: please share your code or post a new question specifying your problem. Thanks

Comment: @SakhiMansoor <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/app/AntennaAdd", id: "123" }} />; Thank you very much

Comment: This works apparently <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/app/AntennaAdd", state: {id: "123"} }} />;

Comment: Updating my answer since React-router has brought changes in their API. thanks for pointing this out. State is perfect way to store values as they don't collide with keys given in API like pathname etc

Comment: Hi... I am having a bit trouble receiving the state param passed with redirect. this.props.location gives me undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: This worked for me but in my case I needed to use `mydata: JSON.stringify(data)` and `JSON.parse(props.location.state.mydata)` because I was passing an object.

Comment: @DhruvSinghal Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sealer_05 I stopped working on React a while ago... Don't clearly remember how I solved this. Try experimenting a bit to find out.

Comment: I am getting this.props as undefined. Any ideas why is it so?

Comment: can you share codesandbox or github link I could look into it

Comment: If the component you're redirecting to is a functional component, use React Router's `useLocation` hook to access the location object.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor currently flagged another answer as correct. Could you update your content to the one that's currently flagged? The currently flagged one could be better explained, have a try :)

Answer (score 18):

You can use browser history state like this:

```
<Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/order',
    state: { id: '123' }
}} />
```

Then you can access it via `this.props.location.state.id`

Source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object

Comment: this.props.location gives me undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DhruvSinghal It means your component does not have access to the router props. Maybe try wrapping your component with `withRouter`

Comment: @SagarKodte Same, mine was first :)

Comment: I am getting this error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

With Functional Components/Hooks, react-router-dom version 5.2.0 and passing down both Function and regular props:

Using @Barat Kumar answer, here you can also see how to pass and access functions as props with Redirect. Note that there is also a difference in how you access the property_id prop.

The Route is the same:

```
<Route path="/test/new" render={(props) => <NewTestComp {...props}/>}/>
```

The Redirect:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/test/new",
    testFunc: testFunc,
    state: { property_id: property_id }
  }}
/>
```

Accessing both props inside NewTestComp:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   console.log(props.history.location.testFunc);
   console.log(props.history.location.state.property_id);          
 }, []);
```

Note that "state" came from the use in Class Components. Here you can use any name you want and also pass regular props just like we did the function. So, departing a bit more from @Barat Kumar accepted answer, you can:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/test/new",
    testFunc: testFunc,
    propetries: { property_id: property_id1, property_id2: property_id2},
    another_prop: "another_prop"
  }}
/>
```

And access those like so:

```
console.log(props.history.location.testFunc);
console.log(props.history.location.propetries.property_id1);
console.log(props.history.location.propetries.property_id2);
console.log(props.history.location.another_prop);
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can come with your own hook for the same purpose :

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const withRefresh = createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true });
const ROOT_PATH = process.env.PUBLIC_URL || "/myapp";

const useRedirectToLocation = (params="1") => {
if(params){
withRefresh.push({
    pathname: `${ROOT_PATH}/create`,
    state: { id: `${params}` }
  });
}
} 

export default  useRedirectToLocation;
```

- and use it like :

```js
 import useRedirectToLocation from  './useRedirectToLocation


const handleOnClick = params => useRedirectToAccounting(params)

const RedirectorComponent = () => <a onClick={handleOnClick}>{"Label"}</a>
```

** this can be further refactored based on requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/path',
    state: { id: '123' }
}} />
```

Then you can access it via `this.props.location.state.id` in the desired component