# Accessing data passed from NavLink after redirecting from home page to a specific page using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a react web app and i am using react router. I want to pass data from the `NavLink` to my `Movies` component. The `NavLink` is shown below.

```js
<ul>
   <li id="movies">
       <NavLink exact to = {{pathname: "/", state:{page: 1}}}  > Movies </NavLink>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In my router, i want to redirect to `movies/all/1` from the landing page. My routes are:

```js
 <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/movies/all/1" />} />
 <Route exact path = "/movies/:genre/:genrePage" component = {Movies} />
```

In the `Movies` component, i can access the route parameters but i am failing to access the data, `{page: 1}`, passed from `NavLink` via `location` props. I keep getting `undefined`as the value of `props.location.state`. How do i go about this? I don't want the data i am passing to be in the `url`.

## EDIT

Perhaps to clarify. The question below partly answers my question.

- [ReactJS - Pass props with Redirect component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064303/reactjs-pass-props-with-redirect-component)

However i am still failing to access the data passed from `Link` when the page is first loaded and then redirected from root path `/` to `/movies/all/1`. It is only accessible  after `Link` has been clicked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - Pass props with Redirect component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064303/reactjs-pass-props-with-redirect-component)

Comment: A possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064303/reactjs-pass-props-with-redirect-component

Comment: Check the edit i have made above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` component doesn't pass `location.state` to the next route (i.e `/movies/all/1`).

If you want to do that, you need to get `location.state` from your Route `/` and pass it down to `Redirect`.

It would look something like that:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={({ location }) => <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/movies/all/1", state: location.state }} />} />
```

Comment: It works but only after the link has been clicked. I want the data to be passed immediately on page load.  If a visitor reaches the site, he/she is redirected from `/` page to `movies/all/1`. That is when the value of `state` is  `undefined`. If you click `NavLink` first, the data is passed fine.

Comment: I don't think you can define the history state on page load. The way you could do that is inside your `Movies` component, wherever you access `page` value, you need to do something like `const page = location.state?.page || 1;` so it would default to `1` when `undefined`

Comment: That is the solution i have settled for. Thanks a bunch.