# Passing data to a component through Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having issues for passing data received as a response from one form component to another component.

I'm using a class component to handle lifecycle methods such as componentDidMount() for api calls to fill some info for select options for a form.

I have looked through the different answers already made here but none seems to work since i get the error

`TypeError: undefined has not properties` when trying to display the data.

Im capturing the data from a response as shown below

**Main component**

```
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/results", {
        params: {
          ...
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        return res.data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ res_data: data });
      });

    event.preventDefault();
```

then using the render method to make the redirection if the form was submitted as shown below

```
var response_data = this.state.res_data
if (this.state.submitted) {
      console.log("Redirecting")
      return <Redirect push to={{ pathname: "/results", state:{res_data: response_data} }} />;
    } else
```

the component handling the /results route is a simple header with a console.log to check for data.

**Second Component /results route**

```
const Results = (props) => {
    console.log(this.locations.state)
    return <h2>Results</h2>
}

export default Results
```

**App component**

```
...
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/signup">
              <SignUp />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/results">
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
```

Comment: `this.locations is not defined` - Where's that even used?

Comment: You are missing some code

Comment: i can present the code from the whole class but it would be too much (178 lines). Im just presenting the where redirect is called and how im storing the data i'm trying to pass trhough redirect

Answer (score 1):

This post is a duplicate of [ReactJS - Pass props with Redirect component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064303/reactjs-pass-props-with-redirect-component)?

The answer is the same as the post mentioned