# React Redirect with props does not render final component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect to an error page by passing an error message inside the Redirect component, via the "state" property.

But whenever I add the "state" property, the component(ErrorPg) associated with the redirected route does not render(and I get a blank page), even though the URL is correctly updated.

I am trying to follow the first solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064303/reactjs-pass-props-with-redirect-component), for reference.

Relevant files below. Thank you,

**ErrorHandler.tsx** (file with the Redirect component)

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { get } from "lodash";
import ErrorPg from "./c1_pages/ErrorPg/ErrorPg";

const ErrorHandler = ({ children }: any) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const errorMsg = get(location.state, "errorMsg");

  return errorMsg ? (
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/error", state: { errorMsg: errorMsg } }} />
    /*** If I remove the "state" property, like "<Redirect to={{ pathname: "/error" }} />", it works ***/
  ) : (
    children
  );
};

export default ErrorHandler;
```

**Router.tsx** (where I am calling the render method in the "/error" path to pass the props to the ErrorPg component).

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import PrivateWrap from "./PrivateWrap";
import Login from "./c1_pages/LogReg/Login";
import Register from "./c1_pages/LogReg/Register";
import ErrorHandler from "./ErrorHandler";
import ErrorPg from "./c1_pages/ErrorPg/ErrorPg";

function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ErrorHandler>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/error" render={(props) => <ErrorPg {...props} />} /> 
          <PrivateWrap>
            <PrivateRoute />
          </PrivateWrap>
        </Switch>
      </ErrorHandler>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

**ErrorPg.tsx** (page I want to render and make use of the props)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ErrorPg = ({ location }: any) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{location.state.errorMsg}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ErrorPg;
```

**The blank page I am getting**
[image: The blank page I am getting]

Answer (score 1):

Was able to find a solution requiring a few changes.

1. In Router.tsx, no need to pass in props, as it is injected directly by react-router-dom. So changed the Route to:

```
<Route path="/error" component={ErrorPg} />
```

2. In ErrorHandler, for some reason, I cannot use the key "errorMsg", so I replaced it with "err_msg" like:

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { get } from "lodash";
import ErrorPg from "./c1_pages/ErrorPg/ErrorPg";

const ErrorHandler = ({ children }: any) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const errorMsg = get(location.state, "errorMsg");

  return errorMsg ? (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/error",
        state: { err_msg: errorMsg },
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    children
  );
};

export default ErrorHandler;
```

3. Updated the ErrorPg to use that key.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ErrorPg = (props: any) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.location.state.err_msg}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ErrorPg;
```